# Unable to display a html response inside a div element

Tags: html, reactjs, api

I am used to deal with Json but this API return an HTML page that I am supposed to display it as it is.
the problem is that I could not figure out how
I tried to view the html using `response.body` but nothing and I don't know how I am going to display that page inside a div element.

I am really confused. any idea?

```
    async function getUserData() {
      const url = `${my_Api}/api/userdata`;
      const resp = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: new Headers({
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }),
      });
      return resp;
    }
    getUserData()
        .then((response) => {
              console.log(response)
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html : '/*your html response here*/'}} />
```

This should do the trick with a proper css attached to this div